# Sourcetree (windows) : Auto close feedback window

Tags: user-interface, ui-automation, atlassian-sourcetree

Can sourcetree be configured to auto-close the feedback window if there were no errors after an operation?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly no option for this exists yet.

Fortunately, hitting ENTER will also close the window.